# .find(".class:first") behavior with Opera and Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using Soundmanager2 to play some audio files in a web site, but not using Flash.

It works fine with Firefox and Chrome, as they support `ogg` and `mp3` respectively. However, it doesn't work with Opera 12.16. Theoretically, it supports `ogg`, and pass the condition `if( supports_ogg_audio() )`:

It is returning 1 in this function:

```
    function supports_ogg_audio() {
         var a = document.createElement('audio');
        return !!(a.canPlayType && a.canPlayType('audio/ogg; codecs="vorbis"').replace(/no/, ''));
    }
```

So it detects `ogg` support. But as I'm doing:

```
currentRow = thisPlayer.find(".total-row:first");
```

I get this error from the Opera console:

```
Unknown pseudo class
[id='total-playlist'] .total-row:first
```

So I'm guessing that this is the problem. How could select the first `thisPlayer.find(".total-row")` element with better browser compatibility?
It neither works in Safari5+ and IE9+

Comment: Maybe it should be first-child selector? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

Comment: @Tony - Thanks, but no success...

Comment: Have you tried $(selector).first(); or $(selector).eq(0)?

Comment: @Tony - Solved with your option. I had first changed all `:first` selectors and it didn't work. But replacing just the mentioned line, it works perfect! Could you post it as an answer?

Comment: I'm happy to help you, posted as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `first-child` selector instead of `first`. See information [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp).